# Language selector - html5 pass dropdown result to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I need to store the result of the html5 dropdown menu into a variable and use it with PHP. To simplify, I have a dropdown with 2 language selections. When I select one language, the result should be stored in a variable. Later on PHP will use that variable to show the correct language.

Currently I have set the variable directly in the code. See line 27 [$lang = "se";].

Any straightforward way to do pass the variable from html5 to PHP? Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<!--HTML form (start)-->
  <div class="lang-sel">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <select name="cars">
          <option id="en" value="en">English</option>
          <option id="se" value="se">Swedish</option>
      </select>
      </form>
  </div>
<!--HTML form (end)-->

<!--PHP - language selector (start)-->

<?php

$lang = "se"; /*set variable*/

if ($lang =="en") {
echo "language set to english";
/*  include 'content-en.html';*/
} else if ($lang =="se")
 {
echo "language set to swedish";
/*include 'content-sv.html';*/
} else {
echo "You did not set lang to either english nor swedish";
}

?>

<!--PHP - language selector (end)-->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need a POST/GET array if you want to do this in pure php; `<form>` defaults to a GET method if POST isn't implied.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="./app.php">
    <select name="language">
        <option id="en" value="en">English</option>
        <option id="se" value="se">Swedish</option>

     </select>
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And get it in php (app.php) with `$_POST['language']`